# Permanent grub2 configuration on Debian 8 (Jessie) installation on Asus X205TA

Tags: debian, system-installation, grub2

I am attempting to run Debian Jessie on an Asus X205TA. I do not have access to internet. I am having difficulty creating additional install media (separate issue). My configuration is as follows:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 is boot partition
/dev/mmcblk0p2 is /
```

I had to copy a 32-bit bootloader to the boot partition to get this working. I can get the grub2 menu and can enter the following commands for a successful boot:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-686-pae root=/dev/mmcblk0p2
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.16-0.4-686
boot
```

When booted into Debian, I can mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 into /mnt/boot, but I cannot run or install update-grub, grub-install, etc. etc. It's not in /sbin, /usr/sbin or anywhere else on the path. My question is: how can I make this grub configuration (which works) persistent?

I have tried creating a `menu.lst` and `grub.conf` files, but neither of these are being found or are correct.

Comment: Have you checked your /boot/grub/grub.cfg? Does it look like the commands you have posted?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `grub-efi-ia32` package which, in turn, has a bunch of dependencies.

First, make your WiFi working. How to do it read on [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/X205TA)

- Install `grub-pc` package and `grub-efi-ia32`.
- Run `sudo grub-install` and in the menu choose `/dev/mmcblk0p2` for grub installation.
- Run `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot